# Lining up dates while reading CSV files

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I have a series of CSV files that I need to iterate through and add to an aggregated stream of date-aligned data. Specifically, I've got CSV files with each row containing a date in M/d/yyyy format (that I read in just fine with SimpleDateFormat parsing), and a series of other columns with other information including revenue.

Before now I've been doing a momentously wasteful process of iterating through every file to get a list of unique dates, then starting a nested for loop for iterating through these dates and reading from the file until the data for that date is found in all the files. All the files are ordered by date, but the logic doesn't have a way currently to start reading a file where it left off before, meaning every time there's a new date, it doesn't start at the last index+1, it starts at 0 and reads through everything again.

```
    List<String> files = getFileNames();
    SortedSet<Date> dates = new TreeSet<>();
    for(String f : files){
        CSVReader readFile = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Output\\" + f));
        String[] nextLine = readFile.readNext();//Parses through header
        while((nextLine = readFile.readNext()) != null) {
            dates.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(nextLine[0]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Earliest date: " + dates.first() + "\nLast Date: " + dates.last());

    List<Double> aggregateRevenue = new ArrayList<>();


    for(Date d : dates){
        System.out.println(d);
        double tempRevenue = 0.0;
        for(String f : files){
            CSVReader readFile = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Output\\" + f));
            String[] nextLine = readFile.readNext();
            Boolean searchContinues = true;
            while((nextLine = readFile.readNext()) != null && searchContinues){
                if(d.compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(nextLine[0]))==0){
                    tempPnL += Double.parseDouble(nextLine[6]);
                    //System.out.println("  Hit date: " + d + "in file: " + f);
                    searchContinues=false;
                }
            }
        }
        aggregateRevenue.add(tempRevenue);
    }
```

I'm looking to come up with a simpler, more elegant solution to aggregating all this information but I'm not sure exactly what I should use. What I'm looking for is outlined as follows:

- Starting off with a folder of CSV files where the lines are sorted from earliest date to latest date, each line in each file containing said date, and various information of that date, including a daily returns value.
- I need to create one collection of daily returns, one for each date represented in any one or more of the files. Not all days will have information, so even though there is an earliest and latest date, dates in between may not exist in the files.
- I want to accomplish this without iterating through every line in every file until I find the date, and have better access to it...

I've been researching a few options, but I'd love some input on what is truly best efficient to performing a task like this. I could figure out a way to open all the CSV files at once and keep an index on each and read through them as needed, though I don't like giant frankenstein collections like an arraylist of csvreaders or making an object out of the contents of the CSV and keeping an array of those. Could I somehow use a HashMap or some other Key->Value pair to better read through this stuff? Have an object of some sort containing an array of Key->Value pairs where the key is the date, the value is the returns for that date. Make one of each of those for each CSV file and be able to more quickly access it?

This doesn't have to be some perfectly efficient program as it's just a tool I'm using to do some calculations but it'd be nice for the run to not take an hour long (67 minutes the last one) where 99% of the program is running through these files over and over to get the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing *" All the files are ordered by date, but the logic doesn't have a way currently to start reading a file where it left off before, meaning every time there's a new date, it doesn't start at the last index+1, it starts at 0 and reads through everything again."*.

Essentially you need a way to save the last line. You could try:

- Create a `String[] lastLine` outside the while loop. Each iteration save lastLine to nextLine (inside the while loop).
- Then when you break out of the while loop (meaning `nextLine` is `null`), you will have the last line saved. You can do whatever you were doing in the while loop outside of it now, subsituting `nextLine` with `lastLine`:

  ```
  if(d.compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(lastLine[0]))==0){
      tempPnL += Double.parseDouble(lastLine[6]);
      //System.out.println("  Hit date: " + d + "in file: " + f);
      searchContinues=false;
  }
  ```

Comment: that only saves the contents of the last line, I would need to save the location in the process of reading through the CSVReader. I think I'll just .readAll() for my CSV files into a List<List<String>>, the frankenstein creation I wanted to avoid, and then save an array of indices for last location in each list.